# Permalink issue with new blog posts > getting 301 redirect

Tags: posts, permalinks, redirect, links, blog

My permalink structure is: https://website.com/sample-post/
However, each new blog post is getting a 301 redirect from a link like this: https://website.com/2024/01/30/

I see that each new blog post is getting the link of the date it was created.
How can I make sure to not get anymore 301 redirects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress site is set up to include the date in the permalink structure for blog posts. To avoid the 301 redirects and have your desired permalink structure `https://website.com/sample-post/`

In the Permalink Settings page, you'll see several common options for permalink structures.

Choose the Custom Structure option:

In the input field, enter `/%postname%/` after save changes.